# How to implement "align-content stretch" in tailwind css

Tags: tailwind-css

I'm learning and trying to use `tailwind css` but didn't find equivalent to `align-content: stretch` on https://tailwindcss.com/docs/align-content

Is this missing purposely or tailwind doesn't support all the things from plain CSS ?

Comment: My guess is with Tailwind you can find a good combo classes to achieve what `align-content: stretch` could do. If you have an image of what you want to achieve, I can guide you on possibilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `stretch` is actually default behovior in CSS, so it makes no sense to use it I think.

[Source #1](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_align-content.asp) or [Source #2](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/a/align-content/)

> stretch (default): lines stretch to take up the remaining space

Comment: This is an old answer, but it does make sense to use it. If you set an element to `align-content: center`, for example, but want to return to `align-content: stretch` at a higher breakpoint, there doesn’t seem to be a way to do so. The same goes for `justify-content`.